# Extend the list of validators in a subclass model

Tags: django

Let's say, I have a superclass

```
class Super(models.Model):
    f = models.CharField(validators=[relaxed_validator, ], ...)
```

and a subclass

```
class Sub(Super):
    ...
```

For the `Sub`, I would like to make the f-field validation more strict and run `validators=[relaxed_validator, strict_validator,]`. What is the "proper" way to do it? I can create a clean() method, but that's typically used for multi-field validation. Can I maybe somehow extend the list of validators in the subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to override field  definitions when subclassing **concrete** models. I would qualify this as custom validation and the right place to put that is [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean). The docs only state multi-field validation as an example, they do not exclude any other kind of validation:

```
class Sub(Super):
    def clean(self)
        super(Sub, self).clean()
        strict_validator(self.f)
```